# Countifs in a cell if certain conditions are met in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to count the number of times certain conditions are met in a series of cells within a column when other conditions are met in cells in adjacent columns. Here is a simple example. I need to count all the times Type Z is mentioned in Square 3 for Unit a. Then, the number of times Type Y is mentioned in Square 3, Unit a. Then, the number of times Type Z is mentioned in Square 3, Unit b, and so on. I would like to run a calculation that basically says when 3 is in Column A and a in Columns B, how many times is Z in Column C.

My actual table includes over 12000 rows so simply counting these would take forever and be strewn with errors and summing them manually would take a very long time and also potentially include mistakes.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand how your question starts compared to how it ends. At first I thought you just wanted to count all combinations. If so, just create a pivot table.

But if you just want to count certain conditions, then use a COUNTIFS formula.

Here's the formula for cell H4:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,G1,B:B,G2,C:C,G3)
```

It's counting the number of Z's found in column C where Column A is 3 and Column B is B.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The formula you have provided seems perfect. I will give it a try asap.